# How to add a whole table by a javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to add a table into an HTML page,using a js function.
I saw many examples for adding\removing data from an existing table,but can't find example of adding a new table that hadn't existed before.
I am having inside my javascript variables with all the information I need for the table,now I only need to find a way to do that...lets assume my var's are v1,v2,v3,v4 and i want to creat the following table:

```
v1  v2
v3  v4
```

what is the correct code that would execute the above?

Comment: `wrapper.innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>' + v1 + '</td><td>' + v2 + '</td></tr><tr><td>' + v3 + '</td><td>' + v4 + '</td></tr></table>';` where `wrapper` is a reference to some DOM-element in which you want to put the table. If the number of rows/cells is not fixed, I recommend a function which creates the HTML string dynamically.

Comment: Post the examples you found and maybe we'll be able to help you modify them.

Answer (score 4):

```
var v1 = 'v1', 
    v2 = 'v2', 
    v3 = 'v3', 
    v4 = 'v4';

var table = document.createElement('table');

var row = table.insertRow(0);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = v1;
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = v2;

row = table.insertRow(1);
row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = v3;
row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = v4;

document.body.appendChild( table );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XPpNF/1/

Answer (score 1):

Start with `var tableElem = document.createElement('table')`

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of answers here should work already.

**BUT!** Some versions of Internet Explorer can't alter the content of a `<table>` element once it's been created. So you can't always use `tableElement.appendChild(trElement)` for instance.

But you can use `innerHTML` to replace the html content of a table instead - that works.

Comment: I think your statement about IE is too broad. You can certainly alter the content of a table in IE. There are just some issues with respect to where you can use `innerHTML`. [Here's an interesting article](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) from a guy who was involved in the implementation of IE's `innerHTML`. *"At first, I thought that IE was not capable of performing the redraw for modified tables with innerHTML, but then I remembered that I was responsible for this limitation!"*

Comment: @patrick dw: It was indeed broad and imprecise, and yes there are other ways around it. I just wanted to note that tables are a special case when it comes to DOM manipulation. Thanks for the link - interesting reading!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQuery, that'd be something like

```
var awesomeTable = $("<table/>");
$("#parentElement").append(awesomeTable);

var awesomeTr = $("<tr/>");
awesomeTable.append(awesomeTr);

awesomeTr
    .append($("<td/>", {html: v1}))
    .append($("<td/>", {html: v2}))
    .append($("<td/>", {html: v3}))
    .append($("<td/>", {html: v4}));
```

Comment: Load jQuery just to create a table? Overkill?

Comment: I was going for a one-rowed table, because it was formatted like one in the original version of your post, but it's fairly easy to modify my answer for any number of rows; it'll just be more verbose.

Comment: @patrick no, of course not :) I just meant that jQuery is so widely used these days that it's a 95% chance that the OP is either using it or it will cover many bases in any project anyway.

Answer (score 0):

just create the html code of your table and add it to an existing div for example:

```
var html = "<table";
html += "<tr><td>v1</td><td>v2</td></tr>";
html += "<tr><td>v3</td><td>v4</td></tr>";
html += "</table>";
document.getElementById('idOfYourDiv').innerHTML = html;
```

You can also build the table using document.createElement(table) and creating all the elements  inside the table, but the first way using the string is faster.

Hope this helps

Comment: document.createElement is much faster than having to parse text into elements.

Comment: i suspect that interacting with the dom and creating all the elemnts one by one it's not faster for the CPU, anyway i mean that it's faster for you to type in this way

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to append the code you created (even if not mandatory for what you need):

```
var table += <table>
table += <tr> ... loop over your data variables to fill data ...
table += </tr>
table += </table>
§("# your wished table-id").html(data);
```

Suggestion given by Patrik is surely more elegant. This one lets you create each single tag, so that maybe zou ca directly insert extra style attributes as needed.

Comment: This isn't even close to valid javascript